# Creating multiple JavaScript error messages contact form?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript.  I know how to create an alert box and now create an error message if a field was left empty in an HTML form, but can someone please show me how to display multiple error messages if more than one field is empty?  Below is my HTML code for the form and JavaScript:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" name="contactform" 
onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<fieldset>
<legend>Your Details&#58;</legend>
<label for="name">Name&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" onblur="validateForm()"><br>
<span id="error"></span>
<label for="email">Email&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
<label for="telephone">Telephone&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone">
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset>
<legend>Your Information&#58;</legend>
<p>
<label for="service">What service are you inquiring about?</label>
<select name="service" id="service">
<option value="Collision">Collision</option>
<option value="Mechanical">Mechanical</option>
<option value="Custom">Custom</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
</p>
<label for="comments">Comments&#58;</label>
<br>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="4" cols="40">
</textarea><br>    
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</fieldset>
<script src="validate.test.js"></script>
</form>

function validateForm() 
{
var name = document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
if (name == "")
{
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="Please enter your name";
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: This code should work fine for the name field. Also, you are missing a button for posting the form content.

Comment: What you describe is exactly what this code does.  So what's your question?

Comment: I actually misspelled a word and found out after posting this.  My apologies.  Do I need to add a <break> because right now it shows this- "Email Please enter your name.  My question is- What do I do if I want all of them to be validated with error messages?  Do I create multiple variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround your JavaScript code by script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function validateForm() 
   {
      var name = document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
      if (name == "")
      {
         document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="Please enter your 
                  name";
         return false;
       }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. One easy way is to use the `required` attribute on the `input` HTML elements.
   it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

```html
<form action="form.php" method="post" name="contactform" 
onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<fieldset>
<legend>Your Details&#58;</legend>
<label for="name">Name&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required><br>
<span id="error"></span>
<label for="email">Email&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" required><br>
<label for="telephone" required>Telephone&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" required>
  <input type="submit">
</fieldset>
```

2. Another approach is to use the javascript as you have described in your code snippet. That is useful if you need to customize the Error message for each field.

Answer (score 0):

If what @alpeshpandya and @Agalo have answered solves your problem (even if not):

I think you are trying to validate only **name** input even if the user forgets to fill it. The [onblur](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) event fires when the **input** loses focus. You have some choices here: 1. you can validate when the user clicks to submit your **form**, 2. or putting your `validateForm` in the others input **onblur**, 3. or something else.

- *Validating when submitting form*: a good way to validate the whole thing and set all error messages at once.
- *Validating using **onfocus***: in **each input**, you have to validate the other ones **above it** when user clicks on it (using [onfocus](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp) or another event), e.g., when the user tries to go to another **input**, your error messages will pop.